# How to avoid posting duplicates into elasticsearch using Nest .NET 6.x?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

When data from a device goes into the elastic there are duplicates. I like to **avoid this duplicates**. I'm using a object of **IElasticClient, .NET and NEST** to put data.

I searched for a method like `ElasticClient.SetDocumentId()`, but cant find.

```
_doc doc = (_doc)obj;
HashObject hashObject = new HashObject { DataRecordId = doc.DataRecordId, TimeStamp = doc.Timestamp };
// hashId should be the document ID.
int hashId = hashObject.GetHashCode();
ElasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(doc);
```

I would like to **update** the data set inside the Elastic **instead of adding** one more same object right now.

Comment: That should help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html

Comment: Nope, that is some thing else.

Comment: I thought that if you will assign Id to doc object and use an [update with upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) that will do the trick here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following set up

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex("example")
    .DefaultTypeName("_doc");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

public class HashObject
{
    public int DataRecordId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to set the Id for a document explicitly on the request, you can do so with

#### Fluent syntax

```
var indexResponse = client.Index(new HashObject(), i => i.Id("your_id"));
```

#### Object initializer syntax

```
var indexRequest = new IndexRequest<HashObject>(new HashObject(), id: "your_id");   
var indexResponse = client.Index(indexRequest);
```

both result in a request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/example/_doc/your_id
{
  "dataRecordId": 0,
  "timeStamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

As Rob pointed out in the question comments, NEST has a convention whereby it can infer the Id from the document itself, by looking for a property on the CLR POCO named `Id`. If it finds one, it will use that as the Id for the document. This does mean that an Id value ends up being stored in `_source` (and indexed, but you can disable this in the mappings), but it is useful because the Id value is automatically associated with the document and used when needed.

If `HashObject` is updated to have an Id value, now we can just do

#### Fluent syntax

```
var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(new HashObject { Id = 1 });
```

#### Object initializer syntax

```
var indexRequest = new IndexRequest<HashObject>(new HashObject { Id = 1});  
var indexResponse = client.Index(indexRequest);
```

which will send the request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/example/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "dataRecordId": 0,
  "timeStamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

If your documents do not have an `id` field in the `_source`, you'll need to handle the `_id` values from the hits metadata from each hit yourself. For example

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<HashObject>(s => s
    .MatchAll()
);

foreach (var hit in searchResponse.Hits)
{
    var id = hit.Id;
    var document = hit.Source;

    // do something with them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you very much Russ for this detailed and easy to understand description!** :-)

The HashObject should be just a helper to get a unique ID from my real _doc object. Now I add a Id property to my _doc class and the rest I will show with my code below. I get now duplicates any more into the Elastic.

```
public void Create(object obj)
{
    _doc doc = (_doc)obj;
    string idAsString = doc.DataRecordId.ToString() + doc.Timestamp.ToString();
    int hashId = idAsString.GetHashCode();
    doc.Id = hashId;
    ElasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(doc);
}
```